# Generalization algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm

Does anyone have the proper codes for line simplification and smoothing algorithms which is good to implement instead of ArcGIS algorithms?

For example any of these:

- Visvalingam–Whyatt
- Reumann–Witkam
- Opheim simplification
- Lang simplification
- Zhao-Saalfeld

Comment: GIS SE uses a "Focused question, best answer" model. In that context, this is five different questions, each of which subject to initial research *before* asking. Please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand how this site operates.

Answer (score 8):

You can have a look at the following python versions of those algorithms:

- [Visvalingam–Whyatt](https://github.com/Permafacture/Py-Visvalingam-Whyatt)
- [Reumann–Witkam](https://github.com/keszegrobert/polyline-simplification/blob/master/4.%20Reumann-Witkam.ipynb)
- [Opheim simplification](https://github.com/keszegrobert/polyline-simplification/blob/master/5.%20Opheim.ipynb)
- [Lang simplification](https://github.com/keszegrobert/polyline-simplification/blob/master/6.%20Lang.ipynb)

Couldn't find an example for Zhao-Saalfeld (yet).

Comment: So OP should just use github's search box.

Comment: @alexGIS - That's what I did ;)

Comment: Yeah, github is amazing that way! I like how the search results are displayed too.

Comment: sure there are lots of codes like these but none of them is usable for arcpy implementation

Comment: But @maryam you did ask to be able to use these "instead of ArcGIS algorithms". This is exactly how you go about doing that.